# How to make my cell values look like hyperlink, [blue] color with underlined

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cell

Previously i have made an application. And in that the i am able to make cell values look like hyper link. But in my new application i am dynamically creating the datagrid and columns, so that strategy is not working to make the cell values look like hyperlink.

I just need to make the cell values **underlined, bold and in blue color.**

My code snippet for previous program:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
```

When i tried the same in my new program its showing an error in Defualtcellstyle// - ->>`telling doesnot contain a definition`

i am trying

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns["Program"].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dt.Columns["Program"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
dt.AutoResizeColumns();
```

Comment: Does dt in your new program represent a DataTable or a DataGridView?

Comment: @TheShaman yes excatly `DataTable dt = new DataTable();`

Comment: A DataTable is just a structure to store data in a table format. It does not have a DefaultCellStyle property nor support any type of visual formatting.

Comment: @TheShaman Ok could you tell me any method to give color and underline n my column

Comment: @TheShaman please do as answer so that i can accept it

Comment: Ok, do you have a DataGridView on your form? The DataTable just contains Data, you need to bind it to a control so that it can be displayed.

Comment: yes. i just taking data from folder and listing in gridview.. thats it

Answer (score 0):

Your DataTable is just used to store data, it needs binding to a control. 
You just need to use the code you had previously and bind the DataTable to the control:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Let me know if you need more.

Comment: i have already did that globally. its stills showing `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` in `Graphicunit.point`

Comment: Try leaving off the last two parameters (GraphicUnit.Point and byte) and change your Underline to FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline. So it should look like this dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline|System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

Comment: Now error in DefaultCellStyle.. My code is now `dt.Columns["Program"].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline | System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            `